# OData: Only many-to-one relationships are supported for nested expansion

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm, odata, powerapps

Following is the query that I'm trying to execute:

> /api/data/v9.1/entity1?$select=name&$expand=parentaccountid($select=address1_city,address1_country,address1_county,address1_line1,address1_line2,address1_postalcode,address1_stateorprovince,name),entity2($select=proposedeffdate,proposedexpdate;$expand=entity3($select=name))&$filter=_entity2_value
> ne null

And the response I'm getting:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": "0x0",
        "message": "The navigation property 'entity3' can't be expanded. Only many-to-one relationships are supported for nested expansion."
    }
}
```

I'm not really familiar with odata or powerapps, only trying to consume an exposed rest service here.

Is there any way I could retrieve the name field in entity3 as well with only a single query? Or do I need to create a separate request for that?

Comment: can you provide the class definition of what are you trying to query? as well as the configuration of your startup. We need more information to help you.

Comment: I'm only consuming the CRM rest APIs. I've no idea what that the class definitions are. What I know is:- entity1 to entity2 is many to one, entity2 to entity3 is one to many. I want to know if its possible I could retrieve all this with single query i.e somehow I could apply a nested one to many expansion

Comment: I think is an application's limitation, I tried to create the same structure: 1) entity1 { name, entity2 } 2) entity2 { proposedeffdate,proposedexpdate, entity3[] } 3) entity3 { name } and not seems to be an OData problem (because the query is valid), but an application's limitation. $metadata#Entity1(Name,Entity2(Proposedeffdate,Proposedexpdate,Entity3(Name)))